# Bootstrap elements positioning

Tags: html, css, menu, bootstrap-5

I have to create a menu using Bootstrap, so that buttons would be centered horizontally in the center on large screens(desktops) and vertically centered in the center on other screens. The thing is that they don't fully do that.
Frankly speaking, that's the way I want my buttons to be positioned

**On desktop:**
[image]

**And on other screens:**

[image]

But here's the way they actually look, when I am using bootstrap:

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwUDg.png)
[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlYFq.png)

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Главная</button>
    </div>
          
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">О нас</button>
    </div>
                  
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Контакты</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am looking forward to some ways to modify my code to match the needed output.